# Nice way to using cast on TextView

Tags: java, android, casting

Question is short. Assuming that I don't need reference itself, would this cast

```
((TextView) findViewById(R.id.someTextView)).setText("lala");
```

be better (or at least not worse) than:

```
TextView tv=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.someTextView);
tv.setText("lala");
```

Comment: I would say not worse from what's actually occurring point of view but defo second option IMHO for readability

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not asking for a code review.

Answer (score 2):

The latter would be my preferred method. It enhances readability, and allows you to use that object more than once without casting it every time (more efficient).

Though, if you are only casting to use one function inside the object, then there's no point in doing the latter (you would just be creating needless variables to only set one value in it once).

Comment: As I said - the only purpose of casting is calling method.